# Hollow Diamond in python

Tags: python

My goal is to create a hollow diamond using python.

Sample input:

```
Input an odd Integer:
      9
```

Sample output:

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
*       *
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
```

But so far, I have the following code that is not working right. Please help me to modify the code to achieve the goal above:

```
a=int(input("Input an odd integer: "))

k=1
c=1

r=a

while k<=r:
    while c<=r:
        print "*"
        c+=1

    r-=1
    c=1

    while c<=2*k-1:
        print "*"
        c+=1

    print "\n"
    k+=1

r=1
k=1
c=1

while k<=a-1:
   while c<=r:
       print " "
       c+=1

   r+=1
   c=1

   while c<= 2*(a-k)-1:
       print ("*")
       c+=1

   print "\n"
   k+=1
```

The code above return a result that is very far from my goal.

```
Input an odd integer: 7
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*


*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*


*
*
*
*
*
*
*


*
*
*
*
*
*
*



*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*


*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*


*
*
*
*
*
* 
*


*
*
*
*
*


*
*
*





*
```

I am actually converting the code from this post: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-print-diamond-pattern  written in C language and will modify later for the hollow one but I can't get it... There is something wrong with my conversion..

Comment: Can you include the result from the current code? Seeing what it actually produces would make understanding and fixing it a little easier.

Comment: Note that `print` automatically adds a newline.  In order to suppress the automatic newline, you need a trailing comma in python2.x.  e.g. `print '*',` -- I don't think that will make your code start to work, but it's one step in the right direction.

Comment: Why dont you think of your own algorithm doing this rather than converting C code?

Comment: I've tried but I don't know where to start, I am really new to python..

Comment: you should add a `,` after `print`s where you don't want a new line (just saw that mgilson made the same note)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you keep using `print`. The print statement (and the function in Python 3) will add a line-break after what you printed, unless you explicitely tell it not to. You can do that in Python 2 like this:

```
print '*', # note the trailing comma
```

Or in Python 3 (with the print function) like this:

```
print('*', end='')
```

#### My solution

I took my own take at the problem and came up with this solution:

```
# The diamond size
l = 9

# Initialize first row; this will create a list with a
# single element, the first row containing a single star
rows = ['*']

# Add half of the rows; we loop over the odd numbers from
# 1 to l, and then append a star followed by `i` spaces and
# again a star. Note that range will not include `l` itself.
for i in range(1, l, 2):
    rows.append('*' + ' ' * i + '*')

# Mirror the rows and append; we get all but the last row
# (the middle row) from the list, and inverse it (using
# `[::-1]`) and add that to the original list. Now we have
# all the rows we need. Print it to see what's inside.
rows += rows[:-1][::-1]

# center-align each row, and join them
# We first define a function that does nothing else than
# centering whatever it gets to `l` characters. This will
# add the spaces we need around the stars
align = lambda x: ('{:^%s}' % l).format(x)

# And then we apply that function to all rows using `map`
# and then join the rows by a line break.
diamond = '\n'.join(map(align, rows))

# and print
print(diamond)
```

Comment: hi.. it really works.. but I don't really understand the code... :) 
Thank you so much, I'll just research the syntax's meanings :)

Comment: I added some more comments, hopefully it’s easier to understand now. If you have further questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Hi @poke, sorry to disturb again, I would like to ask what this line means: ('{:^%s}' % l).format(x)... I really don't get it... Thanks :)

Comment: It’s basically two things at once: `'{:^%s}' % l` is using the [%-formatting](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting); for `l=9` this basically results in `'{:^9}'`. Now that string is a [format string](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) which, combined with [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) basically just centeres whatever comes at the first argument to fit 9 (or `l`) characters. It pads both sides of the string equally with spaces.

Answer (score 10):

A Hollow diamond is the solution to the equation

```
|x|+|y| = N
```

on an integer grid. So Hollow diamond as a 1-liner:

```
In [22]: N = 9//2; print('\n'.join([''.join([('*' if abs(x)+abs(y) == N else ' ') for x in range(-N, N+1)]) for y in range(-N, N+1)]))
    *    
   * *   
  *   *  
 *     * 
*       *
 *     * 
  *   *  
   * *   
    *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def diamond(n, c='*'):
    for i in range(n):
        spc = i * 2 - 1
        if spc >= n - 1:
            spc = n - spc % n - 4
        if spc < 1:
            print(c.center(n))
        else:
            print((c + spc * ' ' + c).center(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    diamond(int(input("Input an odd integer: ")))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not pretty, but its a function that does what you want:

```
def make_diamond(size):
    if not size%2:
        raise ValueError('odd number required')
    r = [' ' * space + '*' + ' ' * (size-2-(space*2)) + '*' + ' ' * space for space in xrange((size-1)/2)]    
    r.append(' ' * ((size-1)/2) + '*' + ' ' * ((size-1)/2))
    return '\n'.join(r[-1:0:-1] + r)
```

- first i check to make sure its an odd number,
- then i create a list of the lines from the center downwards.
- then i create the last point.
- then i return them as as a string, with a mirror of the bottom on top without the center line.

output:

```
>>> print make_diamond(5)
  *  
 * * 
*   *
 * * 
  *  
>>> print make_diamond(9)
    *    
   * *   
  *   *  
 *     * 
*       *
 *     * 
  *   *  
   * *   
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it in one single loop ;)

```
x = input("enter no of odd lines : ") #e.g. x=5
i = int(math.fabs(x/2)) # i=2 (loop for spaces before first star)
j = int(x-2) #j=3 # y & j carry loops for spaces in between
y = int(x-3) #y=2 
print ( " " * i + "*" )
i = i-1 #i=1

while math.fabs(i) <= math.fabs((x/2)-1): # i <= 1
      b = int(j- math.fabs(y)) # b = (1, 3, 1) no of spaces in between stars
      a = int(math.fabs(i)) # a = (1, 0, 1) no of spaces before first star
      print (" "* a + "*" + " "*b + "*")
      y = y-2 # 2,0,-2
      i = i-1 # 1,0,-1, -2 (loop wont run for -2)

i = int(math.fabs(i)) # i = -2
print ( " " * i + "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer has got two corrections, which've been done here :

```
import math
x = int(input("enter no of odd lines : ")) #e.g. x=5
i = int(math.fabs(x/2)) # i=2 (loop for spaces before first star)
j = int(x-2) #j=3 # y & j carry loops for spaces in between
y = int(x-3) #y=2 
print ( " " * i + "*" )
i = i-1 #i=1

while math.fabs(i) <= math.fabs((x/2)-1): # i <= 1
    b = int(j- math.fabs(y)) # b = (1, 3, 1) no of spaces in between stars
    a = int(math.fabs(i)) # a = (1, 0, 1) no of spaces before first star
    print (" "* a + "*" + " "*b + "*")
    y = y-2 # 2,0,-2
    i = i-1 # 1,0,-1, -2 (loop wont run for -2)

i = int(math.fabs(i)) # i = -2
print ( " " * i + "*")
```

Note : Now this works for both python 2.5x and python 3.x
If you wish to know the difference in the two answers, then google it!

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeChoice = 13
N = sizeChoice//2
for column in range (-N, N + 1):
    for row in range (-N, N + 1):
        if abs(column) + abs(row) == N:
            print ("*", end = " ")
        else:
            print(" ", end = " ")
    print ( )
```

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

this code works perfectly to print a hollow diamond where you can set diagonal length upto user requirement

```
n=int(input('Enter Odd Diagonal length :'))-1
j=n-1
print(' '*(n)+'*')
for i in range(1, 2*n):
    if i>n:
        print(' '*(i-n)+'*'+' '*(2*j-1)+'*')
        j-=1
    else:
        print(' '*(n-i)+'*'+' '*(2*i-1)+'*')
if n>1:
    print(' '*n+'*')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hallow Diamond in Python using only print function**

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print(' '*(5-i) + '*'*1 + ' '*(i-1) + ' '*max((i-2),0) + '*'*(1%i) )

for j in range(4,0,-1):
    print(' '*(5-j) + '*'*1 + ' '*(j-1) + ' '*max((j-2),0) + '*'*(1%j) )
```